# toggle not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list and which uses jquery to close and open to toggle between slim and wide sidemenu .

The problem is it now toggles for every menu item instead of only one. right now its also toggling for home , work , music and faq menu. and they should not toggle. It should only toggle ie switch between slim and wide menu, when the user clicks **"toggle-button-on**" menu class  on How can I do this using jquery? really appreciate your help

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav" id="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Home">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Work"></i>
        <span>Work </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Music" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="music">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Music</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="faq">
        <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="faq"></i> 
        <span>Faq</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function() {


                $("ul.nav#menu li ").click(function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg");
                });
                $(".nav#menu ").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
                    $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
                    $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
                    $(".nav#menu .toggle-button").toggleClass("nav-slim");
                    $(".nav#menu li a i").css({
                        'font-size': '16px',
                        'line-height': '100px'
                    });
                    $(".nav#menu span").hide();
                    $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width", "64px");
                    $("#menu").css("width", "64px");
                    $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left", "100px");
 $(this).attr("data-original-title")).removeAttr("data-original-title");
                    // });


                });
                $(".nav#menu").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
                    $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
                    $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
                    $(".nav#menu span").show();
                    $(".nav#menu li a i").css({
                        'font-size': '3em',
                        'line-height': ''
                    });
                    $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width", "");
                    $("#menu").css("width", "");
                    $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left", "");

                });
```

Comment: You're binding the toggling action to the wrong thing. Remember that JQuery methods actually get all elements corresponding to the criteria and bind events to all elements of said research.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil is it possible to show what needs to be modified or corrected to make it work correctly  ?

Comment: `id="menu` appear to be missing closing `"` double-quotation mark ? Tried removing `$("ul.nav#menu li ").click(function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg");
                });` from `js` ?

Comment: @guest271314 i had tried removing as you suggested that but then the toggle no longer works,,, can you show me an working example? keep in mind i want ti to toggle only when the user click on the "toggle-button-on" .

Comment: @user244394 See post. Note, Does not address `css` . Not certain about expected result of `.toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg")` , though , could be moved within `$(".nav#menu ").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {})` , if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


             /*   $("ul.nav#menu li ").click(function() {
                    $(this).toggleClass("toggle-button-on").find(".fa-3x").removeClass("fa-3x").addClass("fa-lg");
                }); */
                $(".nav#menu ").on("click", ".toggle-button-on", function() {
                    $(".toggle-button-on").toggleClass("toggle-button-on toggle-button-off");
                    $(".nav .fa-3x").toggleClass("fa-3x fa-lg");
                    $(".nav#menu .toggle-button").toggleClass("nav-slim");
                    $(".nav#menu li a i").css({
                        'font-size': '16px',
                        'line-height': '100px'
                    });
                    $(".nav#menu span").hide();
                    $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width", "64px");
                    $("#menu").css("width", "64px");
                    $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left", "100px");
 $(this).removeAttr("data-original-title");
                    // });


                });
                $(".nav#menu").on("click", ".toggle-button-off", function() {
                    $(".toggle-button-off").toggleClass("toggle-button-off toggle-button-on");
                    $(".nav .fa-lg").toggleClass("fa-lg fa-3x");
                    $(".nav#menu span").show();
                    $(".nav#menu li a i").css({
                        'font-size': '3em',
                        'line-height': ''
                    });
                    $("#menu .navbar-side").css("width", "");
                    $("#menu").css("width", "");
                    $("#content-panel ").css("margin-left", "");

                });
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <ul class="nav" id="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-button-on"><i class="fa fa-exchange">toggle-button-on</i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Home">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ng-class="">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Work"></i>
        <span>Work </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="Music" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="music">
        <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x"></i>
        <span>Music</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="faq">
        <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="faq"></i> 
        <span>Faq</span> 
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: A description of what you did would be nice.

Comment: @guest271314 it was typo .  i posted the code in fiddle its still not working.. http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/n04mroet/1/

Comment: @JacqueGoupil See comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608902/toggle-not-working-correctly?noredirect=1#comment47364286_29608902 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608902/toggle-not-working-correctly?noredirect=1#comment47364999_29608902

Comment: guest271314 sorry it I was trying to upvote i have to wait 9mins before it will let me do anything..

Comment: @user244394 No worries; thanks for description. Try adding "-on" to `<a class="toggle-button"` http://jsfiddle.net/n04mroet/2/

Comment: @guest271314   I noice when i try to toggle the text in the menu is disappearing

Comment: What are desired elements to be toggled ?